# Javascript JSON stringify No Numeric Index to include in Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i am trying to pass non numeric index values through JSON but am not getting the data.

```
var ConditionArray = new Array();
ConditionArray[0] = "1";
ConditionArray[1] = "2";
ConditionArray[2] = "3";

ConditionArray['module'] = "Test";
ConditionArray['table']  = "tab_test";
var Data = JSON.stringify(ConditionArray);
```

When i alert the Data Variable it has the Values 1,2 and 3 but module and table are not included. How can this be added so that the whole string is passed.

**EDIT :** And what if i have some multidimensional elements also included like

> ```
>   ConditionArray[0] = new Array();
>   ConditionArray[0] = "11";
> ```

Comment: What's the expected output....? `[1, 2, 4, "module":"Test", "table":"tab_test"]`? That's invalid JS.

Comment: Per Rob W's comment, JSON is based on javascript objet literal notation. There is no notation for an array literal that adds properties that aren't indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON structure only recognizes numeric properties of an Array. Anything else is ignored.

You need an Object structure if you want to mix them.

```
var ConditionArray = new Object();
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be an better approach:

```
var values = {
    array : ["1", "2", "3"],
    module : "Test",
    table : "tab_test"
};
var data = JSON.stringify(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because Array does not contain your elements.

When you do this:

```
ConditionArray['module'] = "Test";
```

You actually add a property to the `ConditionArray`, not elements. While `JSON.stringify` converts to string only elements of the `ConditionArray`. For example:

```
var arr = new Array;
arr['str'] = 'string';
console.log(arr.length) //outputs 0
```

You need to use an `Object` instead of `Array`

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript array accepts numeric index only. If you want non numeric index,use Object instead.

```
var ConditionArray = {};
ConditionArray[0] = "1";
ConditionArray[1] = "2";
ConditionArray[2] = "3";

ConditionArray['module'] = "Test";
ConditionArray['table']  = "tab_test";
var Data = JSON.stringify(ConditionArray);
```

Here is the working DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/cUhha/

Answer (score 1):

According to the algorithm for [JSON.stringfy](http://es5.github.com/#x15.12.3) (step 4b), only the (numeric) indices of arrays are stringified.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the first line to

```
var ConditionArray = new Object();
```

you will achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you cannot convert your array into object, for instance you are working on a big framework or legacy code that you dont want to touch and your job is only to add som feature which requires JSON API use, you should consider using JSON.stringify(json,function(k,v){}) version of the API.
In the function you can now decide what to do with value of key is of a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

this is the way how I solved this problem
Where tblItemsTypeform is array and arrange is de index of the array
:

```
let itemsData = [];
   

    for(var i = 0; i <= this.tblItemsTypeform.length -1;i++){
        let itemsForms = {
            arrange: i,
            values: this.tblItemsTypeform[i]
        }
        itemsData.push(itemsForms)
    }
```

And finally use this in a variable to send to api:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(itemsData)
```